# Как поменять местами значения в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

К примеру в БД есть 2 записи:

```
________________
colour |  number
________________
red    |    1
________________
blue   |    10
________________
```

Как сделать чтобы (red = 10), а (blue = 1)?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Есть более конкретные условия? Как определить какие именно значения менять местами? Если уж совсем просто, то `UPDATE table SET number=10 WHERE colour=red;  
UPDATE table SET number=1 WHERE colour=blue; `

Comment: Условия обмена непонятны. Например: http://www.microshell.com/database/sql/swap-values-in-2-rows-sql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL - это язык запросов, предназначенный для работы либо с отдельными записями, либо с группами записей, объединённых какими-то признаками. Попытка изменить несколько записей, которые ничто не объединяет, для этого языка противоестественна. Лучше делать это иными средствами.